# How to create div with class

Tags: jquery, creation

I'm trying to create a div and give him a class but it doesn't work.
Could anybody help me?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).after($('<div />', {
        className: 'test',
        text: "a div",
        click: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test")
        }})); 
    });
});
```

The css:

```
   .test {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    }
```

at the moment he creates the div but the color isn't #eeeeee

Comment: Please provide the HTML too...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

use "class" instead of className

```
$('<div />', {
        "class": 'test',
        text: "a div",
        click: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test")
        }})
```

Comment: thanks very useful! but where is the documentation for this? I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    $(this).after($('<div />', {
        class: 'test',
        text: "a div",
        click: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test")
        }}));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yF9pA/1/

Comment: i have try it but it dosnt work for me. is that possible that the IE 7 is reasonable.

Comment: Try looking at corneliu's answer it makes the class attribute a string literal which should fix the ie problems.

Comment: better use quotes - 
'class': 'test'.

becouse class is reserver word in some IE versions.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $('<div>', { 'class': 'your_class' })
                 .load('HTML Structure', CallBackFunction())
                 .appendTo(document.body);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {

$(this).after('<div></div>').addClass('test')
  .filter('div').html('a div')
.click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
}).end()
.appendTo('this');

});
```

Should work :)

Answer (score 2):

try `class` instead of `className`

Comment: i just tried it on IE8 and it says there's a an error, so yes :P.