# Get html element in the same level

Tags: jquery, html

I need to append this element `<span>my custom text</span>` inside the `<span class="tc-label tm-label">1</span>` element when the checkbox#tmcp_choice_3_0_8 is checked.

Problem is that I can get target the span element by its class 'tm-label' because there are other elements with the same class.

My idea is to get the parent html of the checkbox and then to target the 'span.tm-label' but I can't get to get the parent. I tried with:

```
  aa = $("input#tmcp_choice_3_0_8");
alert( aa.parent());
```

But I just get an alert with this text: "**[object Object]**"

Real HTML

```
<label for="tmcp_choice_3_0_8">    
    <input class="tmcp-field tmhexcolor_3_0_8 tm-epo-field tmcp-checkbox tcenabled" name="tmcp_checkbox_3_0" data-limit="" data-exactlimit="" data-minimumlimit="" data-image="" data-imagec="" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" data-image-variations="[]" data-price="" data-rules="[&quot;0&quot;]" data-original-rules="[&quot;0&quot;]" data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]" value="1_0" id="tmcp_choice_3_0_8" tabindex="8" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">

    <span for="tmcp_choice_3_0_8"></span>
    <span class="tc-label tm-label">1</span>

</label>
```

Comment: That should work... what are you seeing that makes you think it's not working?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I get an alert with this text: "[object Object]"

Comment: See [what does \[object Object\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892465/what-does-object-object-mean-javascript)

Comment: That's because jQuery returns objects.

Comment: You *are* selecting the parent element, you just aren't outputting it properly. Try appending it somewhere instead.

Comment: If you want to get that span, use [`aa.siblings(".tm-label")`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). I also strongly suggest taking a bit of time to learn how to debug scripts using a proper debugger, so that you are not reliant on `alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

1, Create the span

2, Find and append to: `.tc-label.tm-label`

```js
$(function(){
 var $span = $('<span/>').text('my custom text');
 $("input#tmcp_choice_3_0_8").parent().find('.tc-label.tm-label').append( $span );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="tmcp_choice_3_0_8">    
    <input class="tmcp-field tmhexcolor_3_0_8 tm-epo-field tmcp-checkbox tcenabled" name="tmcp_checkbox_3_0" data-limit="" data-exactlimit="" data-minimumlimit="" data-image="" data-imagec="" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" data-image-variations="[]" data-price="" data-rules="[&quot;0&quot;]" data-original-rules="[&quot;0&quot;]" data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]" value="1_0" id="tmcp_choice_3_0_8" tabindex="8" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">

    <span for="tmcp_choice_3_0_8"></span>
    <span class="tc-label tm-label">1</span>

</label>
```

Comment: It works fine. Is there any way to add a class name to the span appended?

Comment: sure thing! check out this for adding classes to jquery created elements. it's easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833701/how-to-create-div-with-class

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple objects selected, what you need to do is to select one of them from that array of objects.
Example on selecting first element:
`aa[0].parent()`

Comment: `parent()` also returns an object.